# PHP Image upload with iOS Safari not providing TMP_NAME

Tags: php, html, ios, safari

I recently noticed on my website that users weren't able to upload profile pictures on mobile. So I copied all of the required HTML and PHP code from the root directory. The location where the profile pictures are moved was also modified so the pictures get uploaded to the right place. Now when I test it out and try to upload a profile picture using Safari for iOS, I get this error:

`Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Filename cannot be empty in /home5/bobcatss/public_html/mobile/profile.propic.php on line 18`

Here is the form the user submits:

```
    <div class="propic"><form method="post" action="profile.propic.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
        Upload a profile picture <br><input name="file" type="file" id="file"/><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form></div>
```

And this is the script that processes the image:

```
<?php 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

include("../config.php");
session_start();

// Where the file is going to be placed 
$target_path = "../propics/";

$filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

$limit_size=100000;
$temp = explode(".", $filename);
$extension = end($temp);

$info = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]); //Line 18

$allowed_types = array(IMG_GIF, IMG_JPEG, IMG_PNG, IMG_JPG);
if (in_array($info[2], $allowed_types))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    exit;
    }
  else
    {
    if (file_exists("../propics/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "../propics/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

      try {

    //insert into database
    $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE users SET propic = :propic WHERE username = :username') ;
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':propic' => $filename,
        ':username' => $_SESSION["USER"]
    ));

    //redirect to profile page
     header("Location: profile.php?msg=Profile picture upload complete");
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }


      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

I emailed the image to myself and tried uploading it from my laptop but it gave me the same error.

Comment: Are these pre-defined constants `(IMG_GIF, IMG_JPEG, IMG_PNG, IMG_JPG)` that are configured elsewhere?

Comment: No, but using the same code on computer didn't give any errors or warnings relating to the allowed types.

Comment: Have you tried `$allowed_types=array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');`? What you're presently using now, are based on constants.

Comment: is the `file_uploads` flag set to true in php.ini?

Comment: `File_uploads` is set to true and `$allowed_types=array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');` doesn't change anything Fred.

Comment: Try `$info = getimagesize($filename);`

Comment: `Warning: getimagesize(image.jpeg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory on line 18`. Nope.

Comment: The only way I was able to make your uploading code work, was to change `if(in_array($info[2], $allowed_types))` to `if(in_array($extension, $allowed_types))`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but this has just happened to me as well and I have bumped into this trying to figure out what happened. If you were using 3G connection the request may have taken longer than `MAX_REQUEST_TIMEOUT` so it probably failed ( *[duplicate here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305351/php-empty-tmp-name-on-ios-upload-image)* )